# Re.search in python regex not working as intended

Tags: python, regex

**QUESTION:**

I am a beginner with python and using regex engine of python. I am able to match several sample regex patterns with my seed file but weirdly enough, I am unable to match lines in my sample file that contains the word "repeat." Below is the context of my issue. What could be the reason?

**Sample Text:**

```
import tset flash_read, flash_writ;

vector ( $tset, (XMOSI,XMISO,XSGLK,XSTRMSTRT,XSTRMSGLK,XSTRMGKEN,XXTALIN,XXTALGPUEN,XHV (XSTRM03,XSTRMO2,XSTRM01,XSTRIADO,XNSS3,XNSS2,XNSS1,XNSSOH, XTEGLOGK, XRXDATA, XRXENABLE, XTXDATA, XTXENABLE, XNRESET, ROOK, XTMS, XTDI, XTDO, XNTRST))

> flash_writ .d0000 .dFF 1 01 01 01 01 X 1; // write byte 0

> flash_writ .d0001 .dFF 1 0 1 0 1 01 01 X 1; // write byte 1

repeat 25> flash_writ .d0000 .d00 1 1 1 0001  0 1 X 1; // wait program time 
> flash_writ .d0002 .dFF 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 X 1; // write byte 0

> flash_writ .d0003 .dFF 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 X 1; // write byte 1

repeat 25> flash_writ .d0000 .d00 1 1 1 0001  0 1 X 1; // wait program time 
> flash_writ .d0004 .dFF 1 01 01 01 01 X1, 11 write byte 0

> flash_writ .d0005 .dFF 1 01 01 01 01 X1; // write byte 1

repeat 25> flash_writ .d0000 .d00 1 1 1 0001  0 1 X 1; // wait program time
```

**Python Syntax Used for regex search:**

```
regex_rep = r” repeat "

for num, eachline in enumerate(files_atp):

if re.search(regex_rep, eachline, flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:

      print eachline
```

**THIS IS NOT WORKING (does not produce any matches)**

Comment: You're searching for `r" repeat "`, with spaces on both ends. Your text doesn't have `repeat` with a space before it anywhere. So there are no matches.

Comment: By the way, you don't need a regex here at all. You could just do `if "repeat" in eachline:`. Don't drag in `re` unless you actually need regular expression features.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is:

```
regex_rep = r" repeat "
```

This will match the word `repeat` with a space on each end.

But your lines look like this:

```
repeat 25> flash_writ .d0000 .d00 1 1 1 0001  0 1 X 1; // wait program time
```

There's no space before `repeat`, so it doesn't match your pattern.

It's hard to suggest how to fix this, because I'm not sure why you put those spaces in the pattern in the first place.

---

If they're there for no reason, just get rid of them:

```
regex_rep = r"repeat"
```

However, in that case, you're not using any features of `re` at all, so your test would be better written as:

```
if "repeat" in eachline:
```

---

If they're there to make the pattern more readable, and you want `re` to ignore the spaces, you can use the [`VERBOSE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) flag to tell it to ignore spaces in your pattern:

```
if re.search(regex_rep, eachline, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.VERBOSE) is not None:
```

You can see this working [at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Q8yUrA/1).

---

If you want to make sure you're matching `repeat` as a whole word, rather than as part of a larger word like `repeatable`, you can use the `\b` special character, which:

> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word…

```
regex_rep = r"\brepeat\b"
```

You can see this in action [at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OVWNi7/1).